# SEO friendly url in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I’m building a website for last minutes holidays.
Now I’m busy building seo friendly url. Each last minutes has one country and one city. The way I want to let url’s look like is te following:
**For the page with all last minutes per country:**
“domain.com/last-minutes-spain”
**For the page with all last minutes per city:**
“domain.com/last-minutes-spain/barcelona “
The url for the page with all last minutes per country is working correctly, but the url for the page per city isn’t.
My routes (I’m using the friendly_id gem):

```
match '/last-minutes-:id' => 'countries#show', :as => 'show_country'
match "/last-minutes-:country_id/:id" => 'city#show', :as => 'show_city'
```

countries_controller.rb:

```
def show
  @country = Country.find(params[:id])
end
```

countries/show.html.erb:

```
<% @country.cities.each do |c| -%>
  <%= link_to(c.title, show_city_path(c.slug)) %><br />
<% end -%>
```

c.slug is used for to the friendly_id gem

The show city path (last minutes per city) is showing the following:
“domain.com/last-minutes-barcelona/spain “

So the city and country are in de wrong place. Does anyone know how to get it right?

Comment: You need to provide the `link_to` or `url_for` code you're having trouble with.

Comment: <%= link_to(c.title, show_city_path(c.slug)) %>

Comment: What's `c`? Whats `c.slug`? We can't really help you if you provide very limited information taken out of context.

Comment: I've updated my question. I hope this is enough information.

Comment: The slug for the city. In this case 'barcelona'.

Answer (score 0):

What you really want to do is have a look at overriding to_param in your models.

Whenever there is any call that tries to build a path involving a model, the to_param method is called on the instance of the model to determine how to refer to it in the URL.  In other words, the part in your route that corresponds to :id.  If you simply override this method, you can return anything you want to.  The absolute simplest way to do it is to retain the integer ID as the first value.  Something like this:

```
def to_param
  return "#{self.id}-#{self.text_for_seo}"
end
```

That's it.  In fact, I recorded a walkthrough for this just yesterday.  The first thing covered, very quickly, is exactly what you're trying.  It then goes on to explain how to expend this out to support encrypted database IDs:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UW_s9ejrCsI